# Internationalization と Localization の違い

Tags: 英語

自作アプリの文言の翻訳をしていてふと思ったのですが、
Internationalization (国際化) と
Localization (現地化) と
どちらもほぼ同じ事のような気がしてきました。

IT 業界的には、この２つはどう違うのでしょうか？
どう使い分ければよいでしょうか？

Comment: 一言で言うと国際化は現地化が簡単にできるようにソフトを作ることで、現地化は例えば日本などの特定の文化で動くようにすることだと思います。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ざっくりいうと、i18nは多言語化対応するよ！l10nは地域にあわせて最適化するよ！みたいな感じです。

> 自作アプリの文言の翻訳をしていてふと思ったのですが、
>   Internationalization (国際化) と
>   Localization (現地化) と
>   どちらもほぼ同じ事のような気がしてきました。

ほぼ同じというよりは、l10nをする際の工程にi18nはかかわります。

> https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9B%BD%E9%9A%9B%E5%8C%96%E3%81%A8%E5%9C%B0%E5%9F%9F%E5%8C%96

詳しくはWikipediaを見ればより詳しく知ることができると思います。

Comment: なるほど i18n は設計 L10N は実装と言うことですね。

Comment: ニュアンスとしてはそうだと思います。

Comment: ちなみに [L10N の英語版ウィキペディア](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_localisation)
だと、グローバライゼーションの最初のフェーズがI18Nで、次のフェーズがL10Nとなってます。

Answer (score 11):

- L10N; Localizationはソフトウェアを１つの言語に対応させること。日本語化パッチなどがその例。
- I18N; Internationalizationはソフトウェアを複数の言語に切り替え可能にすること。最近のソフトウェアであればメニューやダイアログなどのUI要素が切り替え可能になっている。
- M17N; Mulitilingalizationはソフトウェアを複数の言語を同時に扱えるようにすること。Webブラウザーやエディターなどがその例で、複数の言語が混在したコンテンツも扱える。

[Mule](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule)（Emacsの多言語拡張）登場の際にこのような用語で議論されていたように記憶してます。

---

コメントより

> L10N の定義が当時と今とで変わってきているように感じています。
>
> L10N の定義は今も昔も変わらないと思います。昔はフレームワークがサポートしてなかったりやデータがそろって無かったりで L10N == 言語の地域化と結果的になってしまっていただけ

以前はフレームワークでのサポートもないためバイナリパッチの形も多かったです。今はデジタル署名などでバイナリパッチが困難にもなっている反面、フレームワークでのサポートもありリソースファイルを用意するだけになっていたりもしますね。

ところでLinuxの`ls -l`でよく見かける「2月  7  2015」という日付表記、これなんかがL10Nだったりするかな、と感じています。形式はus cultureのままで文字列のみja languageが埋め込まれています。

Comment: オイラ的には L10N の定義が当時と今とで変わってきているように感じています。現代的 L10N は暦表示、通貨表示等も含めての「現地人にとって違和感が無いようにする」ことだとオイラ個人的には考えています。

Comment: L10N の定義は今も昔も変わらないと思います。昔はフレームワークがサポートしてなかったりやデータがそろって無かったりで L10N == 言語の地域化と結果的になってしまっていただけではないでしょうか。

Comment: 2月 7 2015 だと、オイラ的には L10N の途中の状況に感じます。これを日本標準 2015 年 2 月 7 日と出てくれば 現代的 L10N が完了している、と思えます。まあ `ls -l` の場合はカラム数の都合上、難しいのかもしれませんが。（古い `emacs` の `dired` でハマったのは苦い思い出）

Comment: "2月 7 2015" という表記は、完全にその `ls` コマンドの仕様上の問題 (日付が同じ年なら年を省略して時、分を表示、そうでないなら年月日を表示、ただし"時、分" または "年" が表示されるところは同じフィールド) でしょう。

結果的に "年月日" の `Feb 7 2015` というのが通常の表記ではない("年月日" なら Feb 7, 2015 と "," が入る)ので、それに相当する国際化された日付フォーマットが (CLDR には) 存在しません。そのため "月日" "年" と分けて、もしくは "月" "日" "年" と分けた上で国際化していると思われすが、これは間違った国際化の方法です。

Answer (score 1):

具体的に言えば

- 7bit ascii 使うのではなく Unicode を使う
- ユーザーの locale 設定を尊重するようにする
- ユーザーに表示する文字列のカタログ化

といった、複数言語を使えるようにする作業は国際化、

- ユーザーに表示する文字列を英語に翻訳
- 住所や郵便番号の表記方法の変更
- (文化に合わせた)画像の差し替え

のような各地域にあわせる作業は地域化に入るのではないでしょうか。地域化には、その他にも通貨の表示や日付の表示の変更などもあるかもしれませんが、近年は [CLDR](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository) で地域化に必要なデータがまとめられてるので、個々人でその手の地域化をする必要性は大きく減っているはずです。

Comment: +1 どっかで標準化されているだろうと思っていたところにCLDRを紹介していただいたので。

Answer (score 0):

余談になりますが、
ソフトウェア関連で「Internationalization」といえば「Localization」を含む多言語対応のことを指しますが、昨今のゲーム制作／アプリ制作では「どの国にも理解できるデザイン」や「多文化を配慮する」という意味にもなってきてると思います。

例えば、人種や肌の色を多種類にする、Yes/Noボタンを文字ではなく絵（アイコン）で表現する、性的な表現を控える、同性婚も考慮する、など。

その場合は Localization とは明らかに違う意味の Internationalization になってしまいます。Localization にはハッキリと「他国（の言語なり）に対応する」という意味がありますが、単に「国際化」といった場合は、少し状況が変わってきてるような気がします。

Comment: そのI18Nの延長で考えると、どうぶつの森のようなゲームで現地のイベントをゲーム内に取り入れるというのはL10Nと言えるかもしれませんね。

Comment: おお、現地のイベントを入れるのは確かにL10Nの方になりますね。